# Scroll to certain position by JavaScript and

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, scroll

How to scroll to certain positions in HTML using JavaScript such as in this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVdRt/143/)

```
    $("body, html").animate({
               scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top}, 2600);
```

I want to use only JavaScript for scrolling, without using JQuery.